# Paperclip ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip, spree

I am trying to run some Capybara/Poltergeist RSPEC integration tests.

Within my test, I am creating an image and 'uploading' it with Paperclip.

Model: `Platform::ContentImage`

```
  has_attached_file :attachment, {
    styles: lambda { |a| a.instance.styles_by_image_type},
    processors:  [:thumbnail, :paperclip_optimizer],
    paperclip_optimizer: {
      nice: 19,
      jpegoptim: { allow_lossy: true, strip: :all, max_quality: 75 },
      jpegrecompress: {allow_lossy: true, quality: 3},
      jpegtran: {progressive: true},
      optipng: { level: 2 },
      pngout: false
    },
    path: "#{'public/' if Rails.env.test?}content_image/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    convert_options: { :all => '-auto-orient +profile "exif"' },
    s3_headers: { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=31536000'}
  }
```

In my `application.rb` for testing environment

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
        url: "/public/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
      }
```

My error returned

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/system/platform/content_images/attachments/000/000/001/thumb/blue_night_swatch.jpg"
```

I am trying to display the image but I just can't seem to configure the URL properly. Since I override the default within the `Platform::ContentImage` model, it successfully creates the directory `public/content_image`, however during tests, I can't seem to 'demodularize' the class name. Can I specify the URL in the `Platform::ContentImage` definition but only for test environments?

Comment: Does this work for you when you try in development?

Comment: @Jeremie yeah it does work, however not during tests

Answer (score -1):

Put this message on the form and see why it is not saving:

```
<% if @portifolio.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@portifolio.errors.count, "error") %>
prohibited this portifolio from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @portifolio.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <li><%= message %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```